# Country/State Picklist Enable Disable fuctionality

Tags: country-and-state

I want to write one query on Country/State picklist that 
if `( Country/State pick list  == True)`
use this Query
else
this one

Is there any way to find that Country/State Pick list status value? any variable name of salesforce?

Comment: Can you provide us with more information?
You wana do it on custom objector some standard functionality?

Answer (score 2):

you can use List values =
        ObjectName_*c.pickList*_c.getDescribe().getPickListValues();
 for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : values)
        { 
            a.getLabel();
                a.getValue(); 
        }
this will give you picklist value and label